# What encoding does the Ethereum blockchain use

Tags: encryption, cryptography, blockchain, ethereum

Is there a way to figure out the encoding scheme Ethereum  uses? It looks like bitcoin used Base 64 encoding as shown [here](https://blockchain.info/) . Just trying to figure out regarding the Ethereum

Comment: Encoding of what parts? AFAIK they use [RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) for state encoding, and for any other parts the whitepaper whould have the answers.

checkout the wiki for more info: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki

Comment: The block chain itself is binary. Are you talking about pretty printed bitcoin addresses? These are Base58, not Base64.

Answer (score 1):

[From here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/data-structures-and-encoding/rlp/#:%7E:text=RLP%20standardizes%20the%20transfer%20of,objects%20in%20Ethereum%27s%20execution%20layer.)

> Recursive Length Prefix (RLP) serialization is used extensively in
> Ethereum's execution clients. RLP standardizes the transfer of data
> between nodes in a space-efficient format. The purpose of RLP is to
> encode arbitrarily nested arrays of binary data, and RLP is the
> primary encoding method used to serialize objects in Ethereum's
> execution layer. The only purpose of RLP is to encode structure;
> encoding specific data types (e.g. strings, floats) is left up to
> higher-order protocols; but positive RLP integers must be represented
> in big-endian binary form with no leading zeroes (thus making the
> integer value zero equivalent to the empty byte array). Deserialized
> positive integers with leading zeroes get treated as invalid. The
> integer representation of string length must also be encoded this way,
> as well as integers in the payload.